# Parse entire webpage content to text and search

Tags: web-scraping

How to parse entire website including internal pages to text and search from the parsed data search for exact keyphrase in this case "powered by joomla"

Mission details:
1. Extract all the pages to text from it's content (including internal links)
2. Search by Keyword from this massive chunk of extracted pages for keyword "powered by joomla"
3. Show which urls contained the keyphrase "powered by joomla"

Comment: Solved by importing to Excel which automatically does this job

Comment: Post the solution you found as a proper **answer**. You can even accept it, if you like.